# Golang Json Unmarshal string/int64 into int64

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I had meet A Json Unmarshal Situation

```
import (
json "project/pkg/utils/json"
)

type Item struct {
   Id    int64 `json:"id"`
   Price int64 `json:"price"`
}



func HandleJsonData() {

   jsonData := []byte(`[{"id":"1000,"price":"30"},{"id":"1001,"price":50}]`)

   var item []Item
   err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &item)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }

}
```

I cannot direct urmarshal jsondata correctly.
How to solve this situation

Comment: Can you show us how you have tried the unmarshal?

Comment: Use `json.Number`.

Comment: update your question with what you have tried... without [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it will be hard for us to help on your problem

Comment: Note that JSON uses 64-bit floats. There are 64-bit integers which can't be exactly represented by 64-bit floats. If your `Id`s get too large, you might run into trouble there.

Answer (score 2):

```
type Item struct {
   Price json.Number `json:"price"`
   Id    int64 `json:"id"`
}

func HandleJsonData() {

   jsonData := []byte(`[{"id":"1000,"price":"30"},{"id":"1001,"price":50}]`)

   var item Item
   err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &item)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }

   price, _ := strconv.ParseInt(string(item.Price), 10, 64)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

everything works as it should, just fix the errors in the line you are parsing (look in my code)

```
type Item struct {
    Price int64 `json:"price"`
    Id    int64 `json:"id"`
}

func TestHandleJsonData(t *testing.T) {

    jsonData := []byte(`[{"id":1000,"price":30},{"id":1001,"price":50}]`)

    var item []Item

    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &item)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    require.NotEmpty(t, item)
    require.Len(t, item, 2)

    require.Equal(t, int64(1000), item[0].Id)
    require.Equal(t, int64(30), item[0].Price)

    require.Equal(t, int64(1001), item[1].Id)
    require.Equal(t, int64(50), item[1].Price)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).